# How packets reaches Destination through proxy servers?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, proxy, ip

I am confused about how packets from my machine reaches their destination through proxy servers. my machine has a private ip for intranet and we have a proxy server with public ip to talk to world.

so we have three addresses here.

```
1) my private ip address
2) proxy server address
3) destination address (google.com)
```

now in the tcp packet that I send I have source and destination port to distinguish the various programs (like mozilla , chrome , ie) on my machine and destinations.

in the ip network layer I have source and destination address.

I don't know whether http also has addresses.

so when my packet leaves my machine, what address would it be containing. so that it reaches my proxy server through gateways in between. ?

once it reaches proxy server, NAT can be used to send it to destination.
but I am confused about how it reaches proxy server.

EDIT:
should my packet contain address of my proxy server (local private one) to reach it?
I can change my proxy server by configuring my browser. how does my packet once it leaves my machine knows which proxy server it would go?

Comment: The best way to look at this yourself is by installing Wireshark and inspect the stream of http packets.  You can then see the headers and destination. This will give you a clear picture of how things look on your end as a starting point to understanding the system as a whole:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *packet* doesn't reach the target at all. The *data inside it* reaches the target as part of a new connection between the proxy and the server, in completely new packets, whose size and number may be different from those in the downstream connection. From the server TCP's point of view it is connected to the proxy, not the downstream client.

Comment: so this work would be done at application layer where proxy would find the destination in http packet and would make a call to it ?? please tell me if i am wrong.

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI An HTTP proxy understands one thing: a CONNECT command. It reads that, forms a connection to the requested target, and then just starts copying bytes in both directions. It doesn't care about packets: neither should the sender or the receiver. It's a byte-stream protocol.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP sits on top of TCP/IP (along with FTP, SMTP etc)

You configure the proxy server on your PC, so all requests are sent through the proxy (unless they're recognised as local addresses).

When you request a page from "www.google.com:80"

- your computer looks up the DNS servers for the IP address for the host name
- your computer figures out that it's not a local IP (it's on a different subnet to the default gateway)
- Then it says "Hey, gateway/proxy, get me the page from google" (passing the IP address and port for google.  HTTP layer will contain headers such as "method=GET", full URL with path & parameters etc)

Comment: thanks but this is what i know. but how does my packet once it leaves my machine, knows which proxy server it needs to go. i might have set it as different by configuring my mozilla settings. so my packet should contain my proxy server address. ? is this true ?

Comment: The proxy is at the HTTP layer, so the TCP packet targets the proxy, but contains a HTTP request addressed to google.  The proxy forwards the HTTP request (with a new TCP packet) to google with a "X-Forwarded-For" header with your address.