# How should my proxy intercept packets

Tags: java, networking, proxy, jetty, conceptual

I have two web servers `A` and `C`. Because of rules, policies etc `A` cannot communicate directly with `C' (`C`requires requests to have special security headers and`A` does not support this)

I want to create a "proxy" called `B` in Java, to facilitate communication between `A` and `B` but I having trouble with it conceptually.

When you create a proxy, don't you have to change the hard coded URLs on all your services to now travel through the proxy? And then I suppose you must pass your destination as a query parameter somehow, for example

```
http://proxy.com/?destination=mydestination.com
```

Is this how a proxy would work?

(I have found a few similar questions but they do not resolve the fundamental question I am having i.e. [How packets reaches Destination throgh proxy servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922979/how-packets-reaches-destination-throgh-proxy-servers))

Comment: Check this http://blog.anvard.org/articles/2013/10/06/jetty-proxy-servlet.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your own proxy from scratch that will be a redo, there are a plenty of proxy implementations out there

### Spring framework

- Spring Boot implementation for (Netflex/Zuul) https://github.com/Netflix/zuul / https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/

### Standard Servlet

- https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet

in case if you are intrested in how you can build up your own proxy , here is a simple example using spring framework (Servlet implementation is not that far from spring implementation)

```
@RestController
public class ProxyController {

/**
 * request handler for all the requests on the registered context intended to be proxied
 *
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping("/**")
public String defaultGateway(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // edit the original request headers,body etc
    String originalPath =  request.getRequestURI();
    // then fire another HTTP request using the same URI
    return "ProxiedResult"; // return back the result you get from
 }
}
```

the example above is a start point on how to implements HTTP proxy or how it is working there are many things to cover which is droped off like security for instance

Comment: My question is more conceptual though. How does the proxy start intercepting packets sent from A to C? Do I need to recode A with the proxy's address instead of C's address?

Comment: packets are a low level concept which will be taken care off by the protocol we don't need to talking packets when we create HTTP proxy , yes you need to re-code A with B (B is the proxy) address instead of C address because B is acting as middle interface between A & C you can see the API Gateway pattern in microservices as an example of proxy http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html